# Accessing global variables in actionPerformed

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, global

I have defined a global ArrayList `itemList` which can be accessed through a different class. I have assigned values to it via the `actionPerformed` and it could be accessed in the method. However when I try and access the data outside the method it becomes `null`. How can I set and access the data outside the method? Here is the code.

```
public void addMainBtn() {
    for(int i=0;i < mainMenu.size();i++) {
        mainPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JButton mainBtn = new JButton(mainMenu.get(i).item_name+" - "+mainMenu.get(i).item_price);
        //mainAction mainBtnAct = new mainAction(mainMenu.get(i).item_name, mainMenu.get(i).item_price);
        mainBtn.addActionListener(this);
        mainPane.add(mainBtn);
    } 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String str = e.getActionCommand();
    String[] outputItem = str.split("-");
    double outputPrice = Double.parseDouble(outputItem[1]);
    storeArray.itemList.add(outputItem[0]);
    storeArray.priceList.add(outputPrice);
}

public void printall() {
    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(storeArray.itemList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically this is a poor design in the first way. Direct access to fields in a different class couples you to the implementation of that field. Besides, you are mixing up layers here. One layer deals with UI events; and then there is a layer that manages the data you are dealing with. At a minimum: turn that other class into a singleton; and put (synchronized) methods on it, like "add new Item". And write unit tests; then you can be sure that each component actually works as expected, before you start pulling together "bigger" components.

Comment: Finally - if you want helpful answers, then you have to provide more code. Nobody here knows where storeArray is coming from; how it is initialized; and how itemList and priceList were initialized.

Comment: Thanks Jagermeister,

Comment: @Jägermeister Thanks for the comment. I am still a newbie at this and this is my first attempt at this exercise. I would probably clean up the code when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use an ArrayList from two different threads without proper synchronization. Use an ArrayBlockingQueue instead and define the variable that stores it as final.